# Django: Add & delete extra input field using class view at a click of a button

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

What I am trying to do is the following: `User` will have a `production` (also known as podcast episode) already created with the necessary info until this point (`production_id` would be the `id` for this query). The idea is, when user arrives to `ChapterMark` template, he would be able to [create several timestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToCim.jpg) to point out certain topics he/she is talking throughout his/her episode. `chaptermark_id` is created since it would be a `One-To-Many` and with this `id` I can add as much timestamps as I want within that episode. With this in mind, which is the best approach for this type of situation and how I can implement it in my form, class view and template?

Thanks in advance

**Here is my `views.py`:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404, HttpResponseForbidden
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import View, RedirectView, TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from .forms.client_setup import ClientSetupForm
from .forms.podcast_setup import PodcastSetupForm
from .forms.episode_info import EpisodeInfoForm
from .forms.image_files import EpisodeImageFilesForm
from .forms.wordpress_info import EpisodeWordpressInfoForm
from .forms.chapter_marks import EpisodeChapterMarksForm
from .forms.show_links import ShowLinksForm
from .forms.tweetables import TweetablesForm
from .forms.clicktotweet import ClickToTweetForm
from .forms.schedule import ScheduleForm
from .forms.wordpress_account import WordpressAccountForm
from .forms.wordpress_account_setup import WordpressAccountSetupForm
from .forms.wordpress_account_sortable import WordpressAccountSortableForm
from .forms.soundcloud_account import SoundcloudAccountForm
from .forms.twitter_account import TwitterAccountForm
from producer.helpers import get_podfunnel_client_and_podcast_for_user
from producer.helpers.soundcloud_api import SoundcloudAPI
from producer.helpers.twitter import TwitterAPI

from django.conf import settings
from producer.models import Client, Production, ChapterMark, ProductionLink, ProductionTweet, Podcast, WordpressConfig, Credentials, WordPressSortableSection, \
    TwitterConfig, SoundcloudConfig

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from producer.tasks.auphonic import update_or_create_preset_for_podcast

class EpisodeChapterMarksView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    form_class = EpisodeChapterMarksForm
    template_name = 'fc/forms_chapter_marks.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        initial_values = {}
        user = request.user

        # Lets get client and podcast for the user already. if not existent raise 404
        client, podcast = get_fc_client_and_podcast_for_user(user)
        if client is None or podcast is None:
            raise Http404

        # The production_id or the chaptermark_id must be passed on teh KWargs
        production_id = kwargs.get('production_id', None)
        chaptermark_id = kwargs.get('chaptermark_id', None)
        if chaptermark_id:
            chaptermark = get_object_or_404(ChapterMark, id=chaptermark_id)
            production = chaptermark.production
        elif production_id:
            production = get_object_or_404(Production, id=production_id)
            chaptermark = None

        initial_values['production_id'] = production.id

        if chaptermark is not None:
            initial_values['chaptermark_id'] = chaptermark_id
            initial_values['start_time'] = chaptermark.start_time
            initial_values['title'] = chaptermark.title

        form = self.form_class(initial=initial_values)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # lets get the data
            production_id = form.cleaned_data.get('production_id')
            chaptermark_id = form.cleaned_data.get('chaptermark_id')
            start_time = form.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')

            # Get production
            production = get_object_or_404(Production, id=production_id)

            # if a chaptermark existed, we update, if not we create
            if chaptermark_id is not None:
                chaptermark = ChapterMark.objects.get(id=chaptermark_id)
            else:
                chaptermark = ChapterMark()

            chaptermark.start_time = start_time
            chaptermark.title = title
            chaptermark.production = production
            chaptermark.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fc:episodeshowlinks'))

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**`chaptermark.py` form:**

```
from django import forms

class EpisodeChapterMarksForm(forms.Form):

    production_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)
    chaptermark_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)
    start_time = forms.TimeField(required=False)
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**`chaptermark` template:**

```
{% extends "fc/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-success active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%">
    <span class="sr-only">50% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default box-shadow--16dp col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<div class="panel-body">

<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-12'>

{% if title %}
<h1 class='{% if title_align_center %}text-align-center{% endif %}'>{{ title }}<!-- : {{ get.clientsetup.company_name }} --></h1>
{% endif %}
{% if subtitle %}
<h3 class='{% if subtitle_align_center %}text-align-center{% endif %}'>{{ subtitle }}</h4>
{% endif %}

<h5>Chapter Marks</h5>

<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}

<hr/>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary box-shadow--6dp"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i> Continue
</button>

</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**----------------------UPDATE-------------------------**

Was in `views.py`:

```
@login_required
def episodechaptermarks(request):
    title = 'Podcast'
    title_align_center = True
    subtitle = 'Setup | Add Episode'
    subtitle_align_center = True
    form = ChapterMarksForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "subtitle": subtitle,
        "form": form
    }

    if form.is_valid():

        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        start_time = form.cleaned_data.get("start_time")
        title = form.cleaned_data.get("title")

        instance.start_time = start_time
        instance.title = title

        instance.user = request.user

        instance.save()

        return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms_chapter_marks.html", context)

    else:

        return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms_chapter_marks.html", context)
```

`ModelForm`:

```
from django import forms

from producer.models import ChapterMark

class ChapterMarksForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = ChapterMark
        fields = ['start_time', 'title']

    def clean_start_time(self):
        start_time = self.cleaned_data.get('start_time')

        return start_time

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')

        return title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, your `production` object has a series of `timestamp`s that relate back via a FK. You need a set of views for CRUD at the `production` level. Let's assume your models are already created. There's a few things from my experience I want to point out that I think will point you in the right direction.

1. Unless absolutely necessary never use a `Form` class when creating a form object that mirrors a model; you are introducing a need for unnecessary complexity and opening the door for errors. Use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), which can save objects to the DB straight from the view and help you manage cleaning, validation, and more. In addition, these can easily mesh with generic views of all sorts.
2. For this sort of relation (a model object with a varying number of model objects of a given type relating back that object) Django provides the powerful but difficult [`inlineformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/models/#inlineformset-factory). This creates a series of inline forms as needed for a relation such as this.
3. So you have a model (`production`) and another related back to that (`timestamp`). You need to save these at the same time, possibly perform cleaning or validation, and really provide CRUD functionality for this relationship as a whole. For this, you could create a complex view from scratch *or* you could use [`django-extra-views`](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) and their generic CBVs for models with inlines. You can subclass `CreateWithInlinesView`, `UpdateWithInlinesView`. Why? Most Django devs would agree formsets are difficult to implement.

So, to give you a simplified version of how you can do this

```
from extra_views.advanced import CreateWithInlinesView, InlineFormSet, UpdateWithInlinesView


class TimeStampsInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = models.TimeStamp
    form = TimeStampForm # If you haven't created a custom ModelForm, can also specify "fields= ['field_1','field_2',...] and the CBV will create a ModelForm
    extra = 0


class ProductionCreate(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model=models.Production
    inlines = [TimeStampsInline]
    success_url = reverse('production-list') # the url to return to on successful create
    exclude = ['created_by'] # render all fields except this in form
    template_name = 'myapp/update.html'

class ProductionUpdate(UpdateWithInlinesView):
    model=models.Production
    inlines = [TimeStampsInline]
    success_url = reverse('production-list')
    exclude = ['created_by']
    template_name = 'myapp/update.html'
```

Your template(s) will have to be built in specification with formsets; there's documentation and tutorials all over for that.

That's already a lot to digest, but you probably get the general idea. Don't build a horse from scratch ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! Before setting up my `ChapterMarkView` class, I had it as a `ModelForm` (check update) view but didn't get to far with it. Would you recommend to go back to `ModelForm` and replace the one I had with the template you provided and go from there? I am pretty new to django... could you guide me through it? Would appreciate it.

Comment: With these generic views you can just not specify a `form` and instead specify `fields` or `exclude` (list of fields to exclude) and the view will create the ModelForm on its own. If you use a standard form to represent a model object, you lose all built-in cleaning and validation that comes with it. That means that you may try to save data submitted via your form that fails if all database constraints aren't met. It's opening the door, unnecessarily, for some big problems. ModelForm is a huge part of Django and worth getting to know well :)

Comment: Ok, will give it a try. Would you mind if I come back to ask any question throughout this process? Also, regarding `id`, do I also have to create one for each in the `ModelForm`? For example, if you see in my `Forms` I have `production_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)` and `chaptermark_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)`

Comment: I'd suggest following a tutorial to create ModelForm, this is far more than we could cover in a SO answer. But happy to answer specific questions and be sure to ask as a new question for specifica if you get stuck